# Convert table with each field as a different record to a "normal" table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having to deal with a table (BldDetails) with the following fields: BldgID (Integer), ResourceId (string), ResourceValue (string)

Each of the different attributes (ResourceID with up to 50 possible items) for a building are stored as separate records.  So if there is data for each of the attributes YearBuilt, BuildingSize, and Quality, there would be three records in the table.  If there is no information on Quality for example, there would only be two records (YearBuilt and BuildingSize).  I know this may not be normal data storage methodology but I am unable to modify the table structure.

What I need to do is create a SQL that will draw the BldgID, three specific ResourceId (YearBuilt, BuildingSize, and Quality), and their respective values from up to three separate records into a table that has the following fields: BldgID, YearBuilt, BuildingSize, and Quality.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Care to share some efforts that you've done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking this up into pieces, first write the sql to get the values that you need for each building:

```
SELECT BldgID, ResourceValue FROM BldDetails WHERE ResourceID = "YearBuilt";
SELECT BldgID, ResourceValue FROM BldDetails WHERE ResourceID = "BuildingSize";
SELECT BldgID, ResourceValue FROM BldDetails WHERE ResourceID = "Quality";
```

Also a query to get a list of all distinct BldgID's:

```
SELECT BldgID FROM BldDetails GROUP BY BldgID;
```

Now starting with that distinct BldgID query LEFT JOIN out to those other derived tables/subqueries:

```
SELECT
    t1.Bldgid, t2.ResourceValue as "YearBuilt", t3.ResourceValue As "BuildingSize", t4.ResourceValue as "Quality"
FROM
    (SELECT BldgID FROM BldDetails GROUP BY BldgID) as t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT BldgID, ResourceValue FROM BldDetails WHERE ResourceID = "YearBuilt") as t2
        ON t1.BldgID = t2.BldgID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT BldgID, ResourceValue FROM BldDetails WHERE ResourceID = "BuildingSize") as t3
        ON t1.BldgID = t3.BldgID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT BldgID, ResourceValue FROM BldDetails WHERE ResourceID = "Quality") as t4
    ON t1.BldgID = t4.BldgID
```

Comment: Thank you JNevill, that is exactly what I need.  I have been out of this game too long and tried to jump to the final SQL with the joins and get it all at once.  Small bites is the answer.

Comment: The smaller bits works well for this one. You might find something liek `SELECT bldgid, max(iif(resourceID="YearBuilt",resourceValue,NULL)), max(iif(resourceID="BuildingSize",resourceValue,NULL)),... FROM BldDetails GROUP BY bldgid` maaaay work here to. I kind of like the subqueries though. It feels less kludgey.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select BldgID, max(iif(ResourceID="YearBuilt",ResourceValue)) as YearBuilt from BldDetails
```

and then you can extend it for the other Resources.